# Combined function magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, lenses, accelerator-physics

I am searching how a **combined function magnet** for accelerator physics works, but on the books that i have and on the web i can find only patents for this thing, that suppose to know already how this structure works. Has someone some link or book to suggest me?
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean with "works"? Details of its design or effects on the beam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by thinking about single-function magnets, e.g. dipoles. A real-world dipole is designed such that the dipole field quality is good in the center aperture of the magnet. However there will always be some higher-order field components due to design/manufacturing tolerances and saturation effects; in other words a dipole will have quadrupole and sextupole errors, which in practice can be made very small.

But you can go the other way, and intentionally introduce a higher-order field component into your magnet. For example, angling the pole faces of a dipole magnet introduces a quadrupole component.

Most accelerator physics textbooks should cover the formalism for expanding the transverse magnetic field in terms of multipole moments. But magnet analysis is essentially magnetostatics.

Here is a primer out of CERN: http://cas.web.cern.ch/cas/Loutraki-Proc/PDF-files/D-Russenschuck/CAS-Russenschuck.pdf